# Help us clean up the Android tag

Tags: discussion, clean-up

We have a bit of a quality problem in the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag.  Android ranks first in both [unanswered count and unanswered percent among popular tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1320/unanswered-questions-by-tag)<sup>1</sup> on Stack Overflow, both by a comfortable margin.

[image: Unanswered Questions by Tag]

Given that the Android tag on Stack Overflow has been named as [an official Android app development Q&A medium](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/hello-stack-overflow.html), I'd like to organize a clean-up of the tag.

A few things you can do to help:

- Peruse the [newest questions tagged android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android?sort=newest&pagesize=50) each day. Vote up the *best* questions.  Vote down the *bad* ones (remember, [downvotes on questions are now free](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91300/can-we-raise-the-awareness-that-question-downvotes-are-now-free)).
- Edit questions (particularly titles and tags) for clarity.
- Have a look at the [unanswered Android questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android?sort=unanswered&pagesize=50).  Answer any that you can, and upvote any *good* answers that are already there.
- Flag exact duplicate questions for moderator attention to be merged.  (I know we have a particular problem with [very basic beginner questions being asked repeatedly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67595/what-is-up-with-all-the-questions-in-the-android-tag-on-so-these-days).  I'd love to hear ideas on how to make existing answers to these types of questions more visible to new users.)
- Flag questions  for deletion if they're so bad that they can't be reasonably answered.  Some of the problem with the number of unanswered questions is at the bottom of the pile.  If a question can't be improved through editing, then flag it for a moderator and we can just remove it.
- Spend a little bit of time each day in the [close vote review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/) reviewing questions that need to be closed.  You can set up your filter so you only see questions that are tagged [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android).

[image: Android Filter]

Does anyone have any other ideas?  These are all really general suggestions that could be applied to any tag, but the problem is most severe in the Android tag.  The problem is too big for one person, or even a small group, which is why I'm trying to get more people involved.  I'd like to hear more specific suggestions for cleaning up the tag, but more importantly for *preventing* this sort of problem in the future.

---

**UPDATE:** [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) was updated for December, so I thought I'd update the tag statistics here as well.

[image: December 2011 Tag Stats]

As you can see, there have been a *lot* more questions posted about Android programming, so both the total count and the Unanswered count have gone up quite a bit in the past few months.  The [facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook) tag has overtaken [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) as the worst tag in terms of Unanswered % by a comfortable margin (that tag is going to need some attention too, but much of it is probably clean up).  The good news is that the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) Unanswered % had dropped by a full 1%, so we are slowly drifting in the right direction.

Laura Dobrzynski posted several good ideas for improving sites recently in her post on the Stack Exchange blog, [Own Your Community](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/own-your-community-2/).  If you have any fresh ideas on what we can do about problem tags on Stack Overflow you can post them here, or reply to Laura's blog post.  I think a lot of the same strategies will work across most sites in the network.

---

It's been a year, so I wanted to revisit this.

[image: December 2012 Tag Stats]

At first glance it may look like not much has changed, but I think a nearly 2 percentage point drop in unanswered Android questions is bigger than it looks, considering that the number of Android questions more than *doubled* in the past year.  Looking at the total question count, those 2 percentage points represent over 5,000 additional questions that got answered in 2012!

---

<sup>1</sup> Thanks to [Jon Seigel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/136558/jon-seigel) and [Greg Hewgill](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill) for providing the [Unanswered Questions by Tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1320/unanswered-questions-by-tag) query as a part of the [Stack Exchange Community Statistics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89909/stack-exchange-community-statistics) effort.

Comment: I wish I had time to get involved in this.  Been meaning to learn a bit about Android development and this would be a great learning exercise.

Comment: @shanethehat: I'm trying to do the same.  I'm reading an Android book (and reviewing another) trying to learn at least enough to spot the easy duplicates.  Hopefully soon I'll be able to answer questions too.

Comment: And, of course, questions about _using_ one's Android device should be re-routed to [android.se]. (Just remember Jeff's admonition: "Don't migrate crap.")

Comment: Also: To supplement @AlEverett's comment: Don't migrate to [su] unless it deals with interfacing with a computer

Comment: Another problem I've noticed in the Android tag are the number of people who answer simply by providing a link to a blog article, sometimes on their own ad-supported blog.  More could be done to encourage people to expand on their answers beyond simple links.

Comment: @Brad: I think I might need to adapt a SEDE query to find those and deal with them (rather than waiting on people to flag them).

Comment: @Bill - Also, does the above query you're running count closed questions in these totals?  There could be some crappy closed questions that will never receive answers skewing the figures.  Back in the day when delete votes were unlimited, I remember helping to delete piles of bad 0-answer closed iPhone questions.

Comment: I've been studying Android for about 2 years, and the really amazing part of the problem with the Android tag is that there really aren't many dupes.  Android has so many different versions that it can create unique problems very fast.  :P

Comment: @Brad: Based on the current number of unanswered android questions I think the query is not counting closed questions, but I'm still trying to figure out how it's doing that.

Comment: @Bill - Yes, it does seem to filter out closed ones, looking at the numbers.  It may be that people aren't as quick with the close votes, because I see that there are 12,196 questions with no answers at all in Android, and 7,059 in iPhone, despite the latter having more questions overall.  Sorting to the bottom of the [list of those](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/android?tab=noanswers) seems to find plenty of candidates for closing.

Comment: @Brad: Jon Seigel took a look and fixed the query to exclude closed questions.  The results are only slightly different.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The original queries didn't exclude closed questions, but they are fixed up now. Thanks for the bugfind, @Brad. Sorry for any confusion that caused.

Comment: I'm so in! Let's do it.

Comment: I'll start with some SE data dump queries I had already planned. Basically I'm looking for a way to find questions that have a great potential to be a duplicate of another Android specific question (I'm aware that the SE already does something similar).

Comment: @Octavian: I wonder if there's some way to use the Linked and Related sidebars to find posts that are currently duplicated a lot.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40463/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-posts-linked-to-other-posts

Comment: I only have flag and down vote ... no "close" privilege ... Does flagging is the only way I may use to request a close for useless question (duplicate , too old(what is too old?) unanswer question?) How unprivileged user in context of android tag clean up may help?

Comment: @Emmanuel: Answering questions is definitely the top thing I'd like people to do by far.  Suggesting edits to poorly phrased, unanswered questions is probably the next best thing you can do.  Tag and title edits are a good start.  If questions are *just* old, we won't do anything with them.  If they're a duplicate of another answered question, or so poorly phrased that you can't make any sense of them at all, go ahead and flag them to be closed by a moderator.  Thanks!

Comment: moderators not Declining flags on answers (accepted answer posted 1 yr ago, flagged answer posted today) with irrelevant and potentially uncompilable code would be a good improvement as well.

Comment: @CrackerJack9: If the question already has an accepted answer, how would that help?  That sounds like it was just a wrong answer that needed to be downvoted, not flagged.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard the flagged question was not marked accepted, it was posted 1 yr after the other answer was accepted. I flagged the late invalid/incorrect answer as it could have been a comment (unrelated to the question) or deleted altogether (added clutter to an answered question and could cause the OP's code to be uncompilable based upon the information available)

Comment: @CrackerJack9: Okay, I went and found the post you're talking about.  That answer was missing the point of the question, so I deleted it. Thanks for bringing it up (with a flag and here).

Comment: And so long Flag Weight and Reputation for trying to help... :)

Comment: @CrackerJack9: You don't lose reputation for that.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard I did for downvoting it after the flag was denied, and now it's gone and can't be un-downvoted :)

Comment: There are SOOOOOOO many similar or identical location-related questions. I want to help, but I don't even know where to begin. Seriously. What would you recommend, anyone?

Comment: @FeralOink: There are two links that would help. 1. Link to a search query that will take us to all the near-identical questions. 2. Link to what you think is an early, very detailed, well-asked, thoroughly-answered question that we can close a bunch of the others as.  Post those links as an answer below and hopefully we can close a bunch of unanswered questions as duplicates of an answered one.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Okay! Good, workable suggestions. I will give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: @CrackerJack9 - If you help build a high-quality place to get answers to Android questions, your rep, flag weight, trust, and status in the community will be much better than if you worry about lost rep due to a downvote now.  I found an answer of yours which I liked (to an unanswered question, even), which made up 5x the lost rep, and helps you get more flags to contribute more.  Don't worry about the rep, worry about the quality of the site.

Comment: @Kevin Vermeer I appreciate your response and the vote, also agree largely with what you say - but the site does build largely around repuation and I felt a bit slighted that day. That being said, the smiley face was supposed to portray my comment as not being entirely upset. Got a down vote today too, no comment, no other answers and mine tried to point the OP in the right direction as best as possible (add'l info needed, no responses from OP) ... no system's perfect, I guess.

Comment: I proposed a day to clean up but some people didn't like it.  I think there are way too many unanswered questions out there.  Some may be old but others still are valid questions.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109566/day-to-answer-un-answered-questions

Answer (score 41):

At least one problem in the Android tag is pretty evident when you look at the Top Users list:

[image]

Those are *sad* numbers, experts don't get more than a single vote on an answer. [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) is the [Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) of the tag with 6400 answers, but he has less than two votes per answer overall with an obvious down-trend. There are two users in this list that have an unusual high ratio. Pretty easy to see why for both of them, those are sock puppet votes. I flagged the top user before, nothing was done about it. That's a moderation problem.

But clearly, when the Android community shows no appreciation for the help they get then odds are good that there won't be enough help to go around. That needs to be fixed by the community itself, but I have no idea how to go about that.

The query is interesting for other reasons. Putting a tag to the owner of the product produces this list:

```
Owner        Unanswered rate
Facebook     40%
Google       32%
Adobe        24%
Apple        21%
Microsoft    15%
Open Source  12%
```

I personally have seen plenty of evidence for this, lots of open source authors contributing at Stack Overflow. Microsoft makes a good showing with Eric Lippert, JaredPar, Raymond Chen, Larry Osterman and Pavel Minaev active in their tags. Anybody from Google helping out? Are they *still* helping out?

Comment: These are some really great observations.  I can't give many details, but we've *very* recently been given improved tools for detecting and dealing with sock puppets.  Those won't be ignored for much longer.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but I don't think that list has anything to do with who's getting sockpuppet votes. Also, from looking at the all-time answerer list, I can see why you mention CommonsWare instead of Android, but it seems a bit odd to post a screenshot that has CommonsWare second when you call him "the Jon Skeet of the tag."

Comment: I know 3 people from Google who actively helping out: Reto Meier, Romain Guy, Dianne Hackborn (@hackbod). They are in the top answerers of [Android]

Comment: Conspicuously absent in my screen shot.  They are not very active anymore.  Same reason?

Comment: @UphillLuge One reason could be that the questions that could use their knowledge of android are lost in the huge number of questions that are posted(~2700 question in the last week) and they don't spend that much on the site in the first place. What is really sad is that if you remove the top 10 answers from `CommonsWare` you'll drop another +1000k of up votes, leaving ~1,7 upvotes per/answer. His answers are great and seeing the statistic above is not something to be happy.

Comment: @Luksprog Are there really that many more Android questions posted per day than there are C# and/or .NET questions?

Comment: @TheEstablishment No there aren't, in fact `C#` and `Android` tags get about the same amount of questions. But, probably, the number of expert users for `C#` to tackle those questions is higher then the number of expert users on the `Android` tag.

Comment: ...isn't that the whole point of this answer? I interpreted your comment as expressing disagreement. Sorry, never mind.

Comment: Are C# users more likely to have done a degree in Comp Sci or Software Eng?  Or even just to be full time programmers, rather then someone writing a app at the weekend.

Comment: This is mostly because there are **so many localized questions** - questions that is important to a given user but rarely has any benefit for later readers. I (when writing this) have 334 answers. Of those, one has 4 upvotes, 8 have three, a large amount have 2, 1 or 0. There are so many who don't upvote it is really annoying. I can almost guarantee there are more downvotes cast on the ANdroid tag than upvotes. I try to upvote answers from time to time, but most are so localized that even though the answer is good, it doesn't have any benefit for anyone else.

Comment: There is a large amount of NPE questions that aren't closed, there are a ton of questions that barely can be applied to other questions, and there are **so many bad questions** - it is almost insane. Every day there are more downvotes than upvotes, and it is rare a question gets more than 2 upvotes - and same with answers.

Answer (score 14):

### Long Term Solution

I wish I could fix that problem as well but it isn't that easy.

There are three major problems that contribute to the situation:

1. Android is a relatively new and hyped technology, which means that it attracts a lot of attention from all kinds of developer levels.
2. The language barrier.
3. A cultural problem.

I don't know a way to fix this particular problem other than giving it time.

*Note: This is not a solution for the problem but may help in the long run.*
*We should refine the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag's description in the same way you did it with the [scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala) tag's description.*

### Short Term Solution (Combating the Side Effects)

There are a couple of things that we can do to improve the general tag quality. It is an enduring effort however.

I try to hold a so called *Android Office Hours* event in the Stack Overflow chat once every month. This is a chat event which focuses on this exact topic. Combating the side effects. Our last last event's transcript can be found [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15/conversation/android-tag-office-hours-27-jan-2010).

We basically agree with what Bill already pointed out in his question.

> - Peruse the [newest questions tagged android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android?sort=newest&pagesize=50) each day. Vote up the *best* questions.  Vote down the *bad* ones (remember, [downvotes on questions are now free](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91300/can-we-raise-the-awareness-that-question-downvotes-are-now-free)).

- Edit questions (particularly titles and tags) for clarity.
- Have a look at the [unanswered android questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android?sort=unanswered&pagesize=50).  Answer any that you can, and upvote any *good* answers that are already there.
- Flag exact duplicate questions for moderator attention to be merged.  (I know we have a particular problem with [very basic beginner questions being asked repeatedly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67595/what-is-up-with-all-the-questions-in-the-android-tag-on-so-these-days).  I'd love to hear ideas on how to make existing answers to these types of questions more visible to new users.)
- Flag questions  for deletion if they're so bad that they can't be reasonably answered.  Some of the problem with the number of unanswered questions is at the bottom of the pile.  If a question can't be improved through editing, then flag it for a moderator and we can just remove it.

We have a few ideas how to make it easier for use to work on the unanswered question problem.

[Marvin Pinto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1101070/marvin-pinto) volunteered and will take a look at SE API v2 to build a tool for use to gather a list of questions that meet the following criteria:

- Have at least one answer
- None of the answers have a score greater than 2
- Have no accepted answer

If possible it would be good to have such a list as a SEDE query but I'm terrible at SQL so if someone wants to step forward and help, he is very welcome.

Until we have such a list we agreed to start weeding questions out by hand. That means going through the available question lists on Stack Overflow and posting questions that need attention in Meta.SO's [Posse comitatus](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227/posse-comitatus) chat room. If you want to help then join that room and review questions that people post there. It is also a good place to ask other users how to deal with certain questions or answers.

I've also setup a Trello [board](https://trello.com/board/general/4ee8ae5a7d9b13623493c7d8) for the Android tag on Stack Overflow. If you want an invite just contact me (take a look at my SE profile for contact information).

For now this is pretty much all I can say. I will update this answer with more information when there is something new to add.

Comment: This room is frozen for inactivity now..

Answer (score 8):

Not a big poster in meta but;

When creating a question I find the drop down `"Questions with similar titles"` really useful, it reminds me what I'm asking may have been answered already and has sometimes forwarded me to the correct answer when searching didn't help (likely because it prompts you to search for an answer in the same language you would use to ask a question).

It leads me to a solution that has some initial implementation time but, once implemented, could help new or intermediate (like me) SO bods to help moderate questions.

I'm always very hesitant to flag a question as a duplicate (which most questions in the android tag seem to be) without having the "master" question in front of me to compare it to. I define a "master" question as one which has been upvoted and well received by the community which covers the same material as the duplicate question.

When looking at a question with the thought "I've seen this already", I would be more likely act on it if there was a piece of functionality giving me a list of `"Questions with similar titles"`, allowing me to find an identify the "master" question. I could then happily mark the question as a duplicate, linking it to the "master". This would hopefully lead to more self moderation as the asker realises he has created a duplicate question and removes it him/herself.

Any remaining moderation would be reduced to:

- Correctly summing up the question in the title.
- Linking duplicate questions to a known "Master" question as suggested by the "similar titles".

Comment: Pekka [had a nice suggestion for how to modify the site to make it easier to find the best duplicate candidates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116087/another-take-on-canonical-answers-add-a-canonical-vote), though it appears to have stalled short of implementation enthusiasm.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to pay more attention to remove the Android tag from answers that are about developing a mobile/tablet friendly website.

My understanding is that the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag should only be about Android **apps development** and *not* development of **mobile versions of websites**.

We have to separate those things better, because you need to know about different technologies to solve those questions. The fact that it appears on an Android device screen doesn't necessarily make it an Android tag relevant question.

Maybe those mobile-website questions should get moved to [mobile-website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile-website) or similar tags.

Answer (score 2):

Android is a very broad topic. I suggest that you increase the number of tags. Do not allow the generic "android" to be used as tag. Android-Eclipse, Android-Emulator, Android-GettingStarted, Android-Providers, Android-UI, Android-Activity, Android-Intent, Android-Junit, Android-Security, Android-Network, Android-Hardware, Android-Maps.

When I wanted to browse through Android questions, I found them just too diversified, to be under one tag. So I kind of thought I will do it when I have more time.

I hope this helps.

Comment: this is why **multiple tags** exist. Click on more than one..

Comment: @JeffAtwood according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-intent/synonyms the reality goes in the wrong direction. How can we change that?

Answer (score 1):

**An Oberservation**

Android appears to be a area that a lot of new developers are getting into and thus the ratio of questioners against responders seems to create this excess of questions. Because there appears to be a greater amount of new users the question quality tends to be reduced which makes questions difficult to answer. Also there is less chance of receiving recognition in the form of votes and answers accepted so incentive to answer is reduced. I would also imagine there are a much greater amount of hobbyist android developers who are never likely to answer questions.

**Suggestions**

- The threshold for the possibility to edit/vote to close/vote to delete on those particular tags is reduced, perhaps only for users with a certain up vote score on that tag.
- Votes on answers to questions with tags where the up voting is known to be below a certain level could be given more value (perhaps introducing some sort of super vote). Same with edits and flags. It would be like a government incentive scheme where tax rates are lowered for new businesses or first time buyers. This might increase developers engagement with the site.
- Users are further prompted to administrate their own questions and answer.

Comment: Incidentally, I think "new developers" is an _excellent_ way to garner votes. The last time I needed to know the Ruby equivalent of the `continue` keyword in many languages, I found the answer via Google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010039/equivalent-of-continue-in-ruby -- +23 for the question and +36 for the accepted answer. That's the power of asking a clear question, giving a clear answer, and working in a trendy buzzword.

Comment: @sarnold I suspect such a question doesn't attract 'new developers' as you would require a certain degree of experience to know what continue does in the first place. I was referring to the breed of hobbyist developers who are less likely to understand or engage with such a site as stackoverflow (a suggestion for why unanswered question count is so low, and I think if it was checked, general voting count as well)

Answer (score -1):

LONG TERM SOLUTION:

Introduce the concept of a 'generic' meta-tag, for "Android", "Linux", "Windows", or "End-user Request", etc.  This would be superseded (automatically) as an attached tag by any (taxonomy linked) sub-tag.

- You could still search on the meta-tag.
- The user could be warned to select (if known) a more specific tag.

Comment: This helps improve the questions in what way?

Comment: It forces the 'migration' away from tags that lose meaning for being too generic.

Comment: I don't believe the problem is the tag is "too generic" to solicit answers. Most folks don't follow very specific tags.