# Are we removing the Java tag from questions not explicitly about "Java SE"?

Tags: discussion, tags

[This person](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1242160/wittakarn?tab=activity&sort=revisions) is spamming a huge number of edits removing [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) from questions, with the edit message "Not a Java SE problem". Is there a Meta thread where it was decided that this is a good idea? the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag itself doesn't seem to mention this, stating that one should...

> Use this tag for questions referring to Java programming language or Java platform tools.

Comment: If we're *not* doing this, can we stop this person? The edits are being almost universally approved.

Comment: This is yet another "wonderful" realization of the review system. One person doing such mistakes is one thing, but many approving that is even more serious... Why are we always shouting at individuals doing mistaken edits when in fact the whole system is broken upside down? We should fix the system and the rest would be fixed automatically. I am tired of these meta threads...

Comment: the only java-related tag where such a removal typically makes good sense is [tag:java-me]

Comment: @meagar - its not clear to me how this is spamming. Please forgive my ignorance. Could you explain?

Comment: @jww "spam" as a synonym for "flood", as in to spam submissions or "bullet spam". It's not the content, it's the quantity.

Comment: I don't think wittakarn meant any harm, he's just trying to be helpful actually.

Comment: I wouldn't go for such a mass removal myself, but if java and java-se are tag synonyms, and java-se is inarguably an incorrect tag for a particular question, how can java be a good tag? It sounds to me like either the edits are correct, or the tag synonym is bogus.

Comment: @hvd you've hit the nail on the head! This `java` tag is being abused in this way, and also [in combination with the `android` tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254642/deleting-java-tag-from-questions-tagged-androidjava?rq=1). Perhaps we can organise some high-power mods to revisit what the `java` tag really means, and what its synonyms really should be?

Answer (score -4):

I thought the java tag meant "Java SE problem". If I am wrong, I won't do it again.

Comment: You shouldn't have done the mass edits in the first place without checking here first.  Those kind of edits are frowned upon without seeking input.

Comment: Note that tag-only edits are *almost never* good edits. When you perform an edit be sure to improve everything you can. If a question with bad tags is badly formatted and contains lots of grammatical errors you should fix the tags *and* fix the formatting *and* fix the grammar.

Comment: I have not downvoted this answer, but I agree with @Daedalus, naturally.

Comment: You might consider rolling back the changes you made to all those questions.

Comment: @meagar I got this message on my blog. "On stackoverflow please stop removing 'java' tags. The tag is broad and for all java questions - even questions that aren't java ee. If you continue to remove tags, you will lose your editing privileges and face suspension". I think it is not a good idea to rollback or do anything about java tag. I do not know who post this comment on my blog. If this post is come from stackoverflow admin, I think it not a good idea to rollback.

Comment: @wittakarn I agree with the suggestion that you should rollback and in general undo your damage. If you have an actual reason why you think it's not a good idea, please state it.

Comment: @EJP the reason is in his comment above yours - the guy's scared cos he tried to do something useful and we attacked him like we do many new members. Now he's like a deer in the headlights, not wanting to do anything for fear of being banned. And all because (as hvd comments) the `java` and `java-se` tags are synonyms, which means "the same" i.e. a java tag means it is about java-se.

Comment: The tags **are not** synonyms.  If they display as such, that needs to be fixed right away.

Comment: @wittakarn hey don't worry. This'll ease out somehow. Keep focused on your game, and don't let meta drag you down. Grow from this, as this is a golden opportunity to understand what "don't take it personnal" means.

Comment: @wittakarn **The message you got on your blog is fake.** Somebody is trying to intimidate you by pretending to be a Stack Overflow moderator, but whoever it is, they have no power to suspend you or revoke your editing privileges. If a real moderator needed to send you a message like that, they would _only_ do so through Stack Overflow's own moderator message system; you would see a notification about the message when you log into SO or Meta.

Comment: @ChrisStratton [The tags are synonyms](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/synonyms) and have been for over four years. Perhaps they shouldn't be, but they are.

Comment: @ChrisStratton [tag:java-se] is a synonym for [tag:java], not meaning "anything that is [tag:java] is also [tag:java-se]", but the reverse - basically anything [tag:java-se] should just be tagged [tag:java].  Presumably, we at some point decided not to have a separate tag for [tag:java-se], as the far majority of [tag:java] questions are about [tag:java-se], and so specifically tagging the others (ME/EE) but not SE.

Comment: This looks to be a problem with the concept of synonyms then, as those mapping are mostly one-way, not bidirectional.  There are, for example, a huge number of Android questions quite properly tagged Java, and involving java issues, but only a tiny minority of those (involving host-side components) involve Java-SE.

Comment: @ChrisStratton That's how synonyms work, much of the time.  Some are bidirectional, but many are one way: "Here is this tag.  Sometimes people ask things about some really specific part of it, but it's silly to have a tag just for that, so we push it into the big tag."

Comment: FYI, this was discussed briefly back in 2011 [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91401/should-tags-java-se-javase-j2se-be-synonyms-of-java); it seemed like there was some desire for it being a non-synonym but not enough to push any action.  It was also discussed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90917/tag-synonyms-j2ee-and-java-ee) some, this led to the earlier question.

Comment: I disagree that tag-only edits are almost never good edits. There's a reason high-rep users have the ability to edit tags without review, and without editing the question body. Maybe they're rarely good _enough_ edits to be worth clogging the review queue, so they should be done sparingly until you have enough rep to do them automatically, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: Come on, who do you think you _are_ doing mass edits. If it were up to me, you'd be banned for life.