# Shouldn't [java] tag be used for java EE problems?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have recently asked a question which is essentially about Java EE:
[@PostConstruct is not invoked for @ApplicationScoped on initialisation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49278854/postconstruct-is-not-invoked-for-applicationscoped-on-initialisation)

But it was edited by BalusC user: he has removed `[java]` tag with formulation: "Not a Java SE problem."

I want to clarify: is it a valid edit? Because I think that it still belongs to `java` topic. Please, provide an argumentation.

Comment: Since there is a [tag:java-ee], is there any specific reason why you thing the [tag:java] tag is necessary?

Comment: [Old dupe without a real answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275290/7296893). [Related: Split java-se from java](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275290/7296893)

Comment: Hard to see why [java-ee] isn't good enough by itself.  But you can easily rollback the edit if you hate it, google will sort it out anyway.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't really hate it, I just want to sort out these things. At least it is a democratic society, let's discuss and make a conclusion.

Comment: @HansPassant:  Java developers like myself may follow the broader Java tag and not care to follow JavaEE (or JakartaEE).  We might have what we need to answer their question, but we're none the wiser.  I'm not saying that completely eviscerates any reason to do that edit, but it's a use case.

Comment: @Makoto I totally agree with you. The same situation as mine. I don't follow javaEE, but just java

Comment: My general opinion on tags is: If there is a specific tag with a large enough community behind it to handle the questions asked there in acceptable time, go with that tag. If there isn't, then use the uber-tag in addition. We could also tag all [tag:java] questions with [tag:oop] but that also wouldn't help in getting questions better answered or found.

Comment: [java-ee] has 18,900 SO users that favored it.  How many is not enough?  This isn't worth any drama, just roll it back.

Comment: I know that BalusC once had a comment on [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java) where he explained why he removes the Java tag on Java Enterprise/web related questions, but alas it has since disappeared. Still, [Peter Duniho's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321176/424903) sums it up.

Comment: @Gimby That answer is about Processing and Java which are different languages. JavaEE is specified in Java hence both tags should be applied or at the very least Java shouldn't be removed if OP applied it. I edited it back into the question.

Comment: @Oleg correct, but the spirit is the same. Don't know why you edited it back in, seems very premature.