# Are Google and Stack Overflow partners?

Tags: discussion, google

I just found [this](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.ca/2012/09/retiring-google-documents-list-api-v3.html). I know that Jon Skeet is working for Google and he's a big part of the community, but is there really a team working on Stack Overflow for Google?

Comment: [Not exactly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252866/17034).

Comment: Work is done on Stack Overflow for search engine optimization, but that is probably as close as "working on Stack Overflow for Google" as you will get.

Comment: Jon Skeet is a question answering algorithm.  This has been discussed hundreds of times on Meta already.  He's actually owned and run by a nonprofit in Seattle... I forget the name but they have an .io domain and the project name ends in "er" but they spell it "r".  I wanna say it's "Skeetr" but I think they got in trouble with that one and had to change it.

Comment: Seems to me that these answers are all outdated as there is [some level of partnership](https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/support).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Google, like several other companies, has employees who are active users of Stack Overflow and monitor tags related to their products - in this case [google-drive-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-sdk), [google-drive-android-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-android-api), and [google-drive-realtime-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-realtime-api). However, that doesn't mean that there's some sort of corporate partnership - just that that team at Google recognizes that Stack Overflow is a good place to help people with their questions and make the answers available to future seekers.

For more background information on this practice by Google and other third parties, [Third-party development support: hosted by Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253394/third-party-development-support-hosted-by-stack-overflow) would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 4):

Someone who works for one company or the other will have to post for a definitive answer, but I don't think there's any kind of official partnership between the companies. I know Google indexes Stack Overflow (and some other SE sites) aggresively, but I think that's more a reflection of the content the community is generating than an agreement between the companies.

The arrangement you linked to where Google has employees posting answers to questions about their technologies on SO is pretty common. A lot of companies use Stack Overflow to enhance their own documentation and support, with varying degrees of success.

Comment: Google does sponsor a couple of tags which could be considered some kind of partnership - other than that, this is the best answer you can get from a non-employee.

Answer (score 1):

As is mentioned in [a blog article](http://blog.codinghorror.com/if-its-not-in-google-does-your-website-really-exist/) of Jeff:

> Google has made partners of us all.

So in some sense, yes, Google, is a partner of SE.

Of course, that relationship isn't particularly official, merely an acknowledgement of the fact that almost no websites can exist today without having a quality relationship with Google.