# Why is the quality of Questions/Answers so low for some tags?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

Some tags like [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) or [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) are full with link only answers without any answer body or any explanation at all, so why are they so common for this tags? Aren't the moderators interested in the quality of the site as a whole? or are they only interested in the quality of their own tags?

It's very sad to see that here because Stack Overflow is a really good site and I like it to be independent of any other resources as much as possible. I love when the person that writes an answer really cares to explain why would something help and not just [*The account manager has access to this.*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2245959/1983495)<sup>1</sup>.

Morw surprising was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6867076/1983495), the poster added a solution to the question body. And it's [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6989144/1983495) (*added a solution but still accepted an answer, how misleading is that?*) is just a link with 80 points.

<sup>1</sup><sub>This answer was deleted because I flagged it. It had 18 points really 19 but I too downvoted it.</sub>

Comment: "Aren't the moderators interested in the quality of the site as a whole?" We are, but there is only so much we can do. You try handling several hundred if not thousand posts a day all by yourself.

Comment: Likely because those are popular tags for entry-level programmers. I'm sure that in itself attracts some low-quality participation. The greater the volume, the more difficult it is to take care of 100% of the content.

Comment: You must also take note of the timeframe for your examples (the one I can view). Back then SO was more interested in getting answers to questions. Policy has changed since then to manage how those answers are provided (see the numerous meta posts on link-only answers).

Comment: Be a part of the solution. Downvote low quality contributions.

Comment: @KevinB As much as I wish that would help, in many cases it can actually *hurt*.  In those tags that tend to really value low quality questions, the act of you downvoting a bad question/answer is likely to result in way more people upvoting it to compensate.  In these types of tags, at least in some situations, the single best way to increase the score of a post is to downvote it, as it'll result in an over-compensation of upvotes.

Comment: @Servy There's nothing we can do to fix that other than removing the ability to upvote, which isn't going to happen. It's all we can do.

Comment: @KevinB There are times where it really is better to not downvote a bad post, as not downvoting it will result in that post having a lower score than downvoting it will.  It's a sad reality, but it *is* sometimes the reality.

Comment: Moderators *have* focused efforts on helping tags like [android]: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252860/help-us-clean-up-the-android-tag , but this requires community involvement.

Comment: My point is simply not downvoting is just going to add to the problem, not fix it. Communities like that of the android tag need a shift in how that community moderates itself so that it falls inline with the site's overall goals. I don't feel the javascript tag is *as bad* as the android tag because it does have a large base of users who are properly voting on quality, Android doesn't seem to benefit from such a base.

Comment: @KevinB But you, alone, voting that way is just going to *strengthen* the positions that you're trying to remove.  You going around downvoting bad posts is going to make other want to upvote the bad posts that they see *more*, not only on that post, but on others that they see.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I sincerely doubt this has anything to do with the moderators (at least, elected moderators). Elected moderators work across the entire site, mostly handling flags that we raise.

Thus, the *real* problem here is twofold:

1. There aren't enough people in those tags commenting, downvoting, and flagging where necessary.
2. Those techs are *really* popular so there are a lot of people who have no business asking a question trying to use them, failing, and asking anyways.

The combination makes for a quality decrease. Since we can't really solve the second one, the only real fix I see is the community around those tags working at cleaning it up.

Comment: Well I have been editing as many posts as I can to help in that task. And I see your point about moderators responsibility.

Comment: @iharob That's great! Now you have to get all your peers to do the same. With the influx in popular tags, the entire community has to rally around keeping it clean, or it all becomes [tag:php]

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot php. I don't do much work with those languages except that recently some work has required me to use them and that's why I have been looking up material on google, which always leads me to Stack Overflow of course.

Answer (score 8):

I see it as a combination of several things:

- There are a ***lot*** of people using JavaScript and Android as their development platforms
- There are a ***lot*** of people that have questions about the subject
- There are a ***lot*** of poorly phrased or researched questions about these technologies, some of which are duplicated or grossly off-topic

In all reality, we need more people to identify poor questions and answers in those technologies.  We need folks to close duplicates and help keep the general amount of information good and easy to access.

This doesn't fall on the elected moderators; they are not subject matter experts.  This falls on the community-at-large; those of us who actually spend time in these tags and can truly pick out what is good and what is bad.

Answer (score 7):

SO isn't so much a community as it is a collection of smaller communities centered around languages/topics.

Particular languages, tools, topics, etc. (a.k.a. tags) tend to develop communities over time.  People tend to follow particular tags, in many cases a fairly small number of them; these tags have regulars, and as the same people begin interacting with each other they develop relationships, start to create common values, etc.  To a degree, the direction of these communities can be influenced by the design of the site, but only to a degree.  The communities within each site can, in some cases, vary fairly widely in their values.

Once a community begins to take hold, it builds up inertia; the values of that community tend to strengthen over time.  People interested in that topic/language but who's values tend to differ strongly from the community will either begin to assimilate, or leave and find a different site that they feel is better suited to them.

Of the things that SO communities value, is the quality of posts.  They'll also vary in how they reflect those values.  Some of the tag communities in SO have developed a very high standard of quality, and posts that don't meet those standards will be downvoted, closed, etc.  People that like being on a site with higher standards will stay, and continue to vote in line with those standards, and those who would prefer to be much more lenient will often get frustrated, and will often leave.

Conversely, some of the tag communities have developed around a much lower standard.  Questions asked in one language that might get downvotes and close votes in one tag may get upvotes and no close votes (and reopen votes if it gets closed) in another community that has developed much more lax standards.  People who get frustrated at a lack of quality will often leave, thus reducing the number of people downvoting and voting to close low quality content.  Since these people are much more likely to leave, it means low quality questions get upvotes, not downvotes, and stay open, further pushing the community down that direction.

Because of these, you'll find that the users who were the most active just as the tags were just getting started on the site were those that shaped the initial values of each community, simply because it's so hard for them to change over time.  If the people answering [android] questions when that tag first started growing on SO were people willing up upvote anything, answer anything, and who weren't closing questions meeting close criteria, then those were the values that would spread to other new users.

Note that the *vast overwhelming* majority of moderation activities performed on SO is community moderation.  Elected moderators perform a minuscule portion of the actual moderation done on the site.  As far as a macro level trending of how the site is moderated, how the elected mods choose to handle various situations tends to be insignificant.

Another factor is how quickly that tag's community develops.  Communities that spring up really quickly (a.k.a android) end up with a much higher percentage of lower reputation users that don't have the moderation privileges than communities that are built more slowly (in particular, tags that had communities being built when the whole site was much smaller, such as java/C/C++/C#.  By growing very quickly there simply aren't enough people with the ability to close questions to close all of the questions that merit closure, so the people asking close-worthy questions continue asking them, getting upvotes, and then becoming the people who are deciding what questions should be closed.

It also takes time for newer users to assimilate into SO and begin to understand its goals, and how it's different from other sites.  When a community is growing quickly then new users tend to be interacting with other new users, rather than more established users that might have higher standards, understand how moderation on the site works, and who realize that SO isn't meant be like other forums where its okay to ask any kind of question.

Comment: "how the elected mods choose to handle various situations tends to be insignificant" [mfw](https://derpibooru.org/383353)

Comment: @BoltClock If it makes you feel better your actions as a moderator tend to mean more than any other individual community member.  It's just insignificant in the face of the sheer number of community members that contribute to the site's moderation.