# Why do all programming questions get asked on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Why would anyone think all languages have the same answers?

I think it's absolutely brainless to combine so many languages onto one stack site, whilst the likelihood of ever receiving a precise answer is constantly decreasing due to the fact that nobody knows every programming language out there.

Can someone please tell me how iPhone development has anything to do with Android development, or how Python has anything to do with XML layouts?  I'm getting sick of having my questions removed from Android Enthusiasts to be put on Stack Overflow and never getting an answer!

Can someone please make designated stack sites for these languages?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. When asking a question you tag it with the appropriate languages/technologies. That's how you make sure the question is attracting people who would know the answer. It's not like all the questions are dumped in the same bucket and have to fend for themselves.

Comment: Why are you asking this on MSO? Ask Android Enthusiasts why they don't want programming questions.

Comment: @NathanTuggy:  Enthusiasts don't want to be bothered with the technical programming jargon, and in reality, we shouldn't be bothering those who are only enthused about the platform with hard programming questions.

Comment: @Makoto: Sure, I can easily see that that's a reasonable explanation. Point is, it's not *SO*'s policy that's causing trouble here. If AE doesn't want the questions (for what certainly seem to be decent reasons), we aren't going to be able to make them change their minds. So this is just the wrong meta for the question entirely.

Comment: @NathanTuggy:  Not necessarily.  There's been talk of splitting up Stack Overflow in the past, and for whatever it's worth, I've often thought about having a separate Java.SE.

Comment: Java SE would be perfect !

Comment: This is an awful idea. There's a thing called tags. People subscribe to the tags they're good at. The effect is pretty much as if there were separate sites for each language, with the exception that if you are good at *multiple* tags (most people are) you don't have to subscribe to five different sites, which would be a giant mightmare. If you're not getting your questions answered it might be worth taking a look at them to see why.

Comment: Let's say I have a client/server program. The client is written in language A, the server in B. For some reason I can't get some data to transfer correctly. I've an mcve, I know what's supposed to happen but I don't know whether the issue is in the client or the server code. Where would I ask this question in your new single language world?

Comment: Oh, yes Java SE would be perfect. All Java and the Script ones in a single bin ...

Comment: @rene migrate all Java and JS questions onto http://coffee.stackexchange.com/, for consistency's sake

Comment: A very large number of Android questions don't get answered simply because they are low quality. This isn't new. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252860/help-us-clean-up-the-android-tag

Comment: Wait, your questions are migrated because you posted them on the wrong site and you are suggesting creating umpteen new sites which makes it even harder to find the correct one to ask your question on?

Answer (score 20):

You can mostly sequester yourself into specific languages by adding specific tags to your [favorite tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19177/175248).  There's no reason to bother surfing the sea of *all* questions, since you're right; not everyone knows the answer to *all* questions.

But, there's nothing wrong with keeping niches on this site.  It isn't like a software developer that *only* knows iPhone development is entirely worthless here, and they can also safely ignore any language/development platform that they don't wish to interface with.

Comment: I know you can separate questions with tags, but that's useless for people scrolling through hundreds questions to   find a language they can answer !  .... If it was separated, everyone would get an answer .. Instead %60 of questions never get answered

Comment: @Noob nobody scrolls through hundreds of questions until they find something they can answer. That's the *point* of tags.

Comment: I don't know if you Guy's use the app ( Android App ) but you can't separate questions by tags ! only scroll through the list of questions an identify the tag's individually

Comment: @NoobFood: I make heavy use of the mobile app, but I don't normally use it to answer. Again, it's not tough to find questions you can answer based on tags.

Answer (score 17):

> I'm getting sick of having my questions removed from Android
>   Enthusiasts to be put on Stack Overflow and never getting an answer !

First, you should always check the Help Center of any Stack Exchange site you go to before asking a question. Their [help center](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) explicitly states:

> Development/programming questions are not covered on this site. You
>   can visit our sister site, Stack Overflow, instead.

So your questions are getting migrated because they're off topic there. As for not getting answers, you should use [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) including the additional links at the bottom to improve your questions. Editing a question puts it at the top of the active questions queue, which can help it get more attention. You also have enough rep on this site to put a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) on your question.

> Can someone please make designated stack sites...

There are already Stack Exchanges for specific topics like:

- [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)
- [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- [TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)

If you have an idea for a new Stack Exchange, take it to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq). That's where site proposals are created.

That said, I do agree with Makoto that the problem isn't the presence of questions of other topics. The Android tag has 220K users following it; anyone who wants to answer Android questions knows where to go.