# Are there "quality statistics" per tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

(disclaimer: sorry for the ranting like parts to follow)

I am currently two upvotes away from the bronze badge for arraylist; and: boy, getting there felt *hard*. I can't wait for the answer there that pushes me to 100 ... update: now that I got it; it feels almost as good as reaching that Elite badge some months back. Almost.

What I mean is: it *feels* like every time I check for new questions there, I just find a pile of rubbish. Questions that are either unclear, or some dup of "index out of bounds" duplicate, or whatnot.

Now I am simply wondering: are there any specific "quality metrics" in place? The tags overview sorts them by usage count; but I am wondering: is there some simple overview somewhere, that would give things like:

- number of questions that got answers
- number of questions that got downvoted / closed / deleted ...

for a specific tag?

Comment: OK, that would mean: build my own query ... but on pre-build "dashboard" somewhere

Comment: Bill had a query for pulling some of those stats here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252860/help-us-clean-up-the-android-tag when he was rallying support to clean up [android].

Comment: @BradLarson If you turn that into an answer, I would have to accept somethin' later on ...

Comment: I asked for some sort of stats for the year-in review... https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272085/213575