# The Three.js tag has really bad questions

Tags: discussion

The distribution of [three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/three.js) tagged question is something like this:

#### 1 x

super clear, graphics / WebGL / GLSL / JavaScript related question for the library, that makes sense, is properly formatted and helps the community.

#### 19 x

confusing, lazy, ill-formatted questions that make no sense, and are often not even remotely three.js related (basic JavaScript or DOM)

#### What can be done to remedy this?

I notice a lot of the questions simply go unanswered. Some do get downvoted though.

I find myself writing more comments than answers lately. Sometimes I link to [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and sometimes I explain why the question is not three.js-related and remove the tags.

Other times, users accept answers that are wrong. They ask one question, but within there's a different problem hidden. The accepted answer usually focuses on the problem, rather than the question. This is when I usually suggest to edit the question, but some times I urged for the different answers to be accepted.

It doesn't seem that there are too many people responding to `three.js`, and I'm also under the impression that a lot of the questions are asked by people who register specifically to ask that question.

Is it possible to somehow urge the users to read MCVE before posting a question with this tag?

Comment: _"Is it possible to somehow urge the users to read mcve before posting a question with this tag?"_ Do you really think the situation is better with other tags?

Comment: That's the same for all tags related to topics that are easily accessible. And it is that time of the year where all students get their assignments for the winter term.

Comment: BTW, these OP's maybe _urged_ when their questions get closed because of the missing [MCVE]. Yes, that's an actual close (flagging) reason, so please do so.

Comment: Hey, at 90%, you're in full compliance with Sturgeon's law.

Comment: 1) get rss reader with feed to tag 2) check every new question 3) downvote, vote to close. Perhaps create a canned script to let them know why the question stinks.

Comment: Yikes, [40.3% unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/three.js/topusers) all-time on 11.5k questions. Worse than [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/topusers), but still not quite as bad as [Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/facebook/topusers).

Comment: @BilltheLizard can you put that into context? Is it good or bad? This is pretty much the only tag i follow. It's supposed to be a very popular library. Judging by the names of the two other tags you mention, it seems that these numbers are actually normal?

Comment: Overall, Stack Overflow has about 29% unanswered rate. Many of the most popular tags are right round that level. Less popular tags vary pretty widely. Perl and C seem to hover around 10-15%, which is quite good. 40% though is really bad.

Comment: (Facebook and Android are both pretty bad. Platforms that are popular among non-programmers seem to attract a lot of inexperienced developers.)

Comment: There is a bit more to it, [three.js] certainly had a decent set of experts.  They however no longer show up or rarely contribute anymore.  Voting is quite abysmal.  Only 1 in 4 questions get an answer in a week.  The question volume has not changed since 2013.  Unlike [android] it looks like it reached a tipping point where everybody just threw up their hands and gave up.  Rot.  This is something that TeamDAG needs to fix.

Comment: This is getting a bit over my head. Was this... issue (if it is one) even worth raising?

Comment: @pailhead: "*What can be done to remedy this?*" Welcome to how *every* 3D graphics-related tag looks. Nothing draws first-time-game-developers/programmers like 3D graphics stuff. I imagine that many C/C++ programmers have the OpenGL (and related) tags on their ignore list.

Comment: It entirely depends on the community behind that tag. OpenGL, for example has 23.8% unanswered and multiple active users (including @NicolBolas). But I completely agree with his conclusion: 3D graphics attracts a lot of beginners who neither have the math skills nor the programming skills to handle these APIs.

Comment: _3D graphics attracts a lot of beginners who neither have the math skills nor the programming skills to handle these APIs_ ... and that's the reason they should give up straightaway, right? Wow. No questions asked. It seems that nowadays in the world of 3D graphics (or should I say, graphic designers) you either have inborn broad knowledge of everything or you get the hell out.  <3

Comment: Yes, they should give up trying to rotate something if they have no idea what Eulers or Quaternions are, they should give up trying to translate something if they have no idea what a Vector is. They need to go learn that first and then come back. Most of the graphics books i have first cover the basics of the graphics pipeline, then math, then actual code. Otherwise, what do you suggest? Being barely over 40% unanswered questions does not sound like enough? An unanswered question does nothing here.

Comment: It's a broad topic, it requires some time to be invested, asking for a shortcut seems pointless, hence the great number of unanswered questions.

Comment: @Skipper take a look [at this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46549830/point-on-a-object-in-three-js) if you will. I may totally be in the wrong here, but this seemed to me like the most inappropriate format. User can't even explain what they need (they already posted the same questino) and a good samaritan goes and does their job for them.

Comment: While it's fine to help, i don't see how this can be useful to anyone else. The user has no idea what is actually going on, and because it took so many words and an entire chat session to solve this, i doubt that anyone else would benefit from this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Was this... issue (if it is one) even worth raising?

It's always worth raising issues so that people are aware of them. However, it is [really difficult to get a low-performing tag cleaned up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252860/help-us-clean-up-the-android-tag).

The best thing you can do is spend your own time answering what questions you can, up voting good answers, and down voting/close voting bad questions. Consider adding bounties to particularly good unanswered questions, and maybe post them on social media (Twitter if you have interested followers, reddit if there's a community there dedicated to the tag you're trying to clean up).

Comment: I linked this to the repo, and it might be a good idea to post to reddit and three discourse. I agree with the approach, but an individual can't do much. Feels like a more consolidated strategy is needed. Should I also post a call to action like the question you linked to?

Comment: Yeah, it was definitely a lot of work to move the needle on the Android tag even a point or two. I forgot to mention that you could look for (or create) an SO chat room on the tag you're trying to clean up. The Android chat rooms were probably the biggest help of all when I was active in that effort. You could add a call to action to this post. Maybe take a look at tags that have similar traffic as `three.js`, similar to how I did the top tags before?

Answer (score 4):

A lot of the three.js experts now hang out on the official [forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/) which has a much higher response rate and was created about 6 months ago. That could be at least part of the issue.

Comment: Same thing except without votes and the ability to edit. Also plagued by that one guy advertising his `infinite time-varying geometries` in every thread :(

I'm not sure if i like that medium TBH. Github seems to refer people to SO not to the forum.

Comment: '...that one guy advertising his infinite time-varying geometries in every thread'

What? I'm on there everyday and I've never seen that.

Comment: As for ability to edit, well, I do that everyday.  If you don't think I do it enough, or want to be a mod too then let me know ;)

Comment: i may have exaggerated a bit :D, but i do remember reading something completely unrelated when i saw that being mentioned